# Не могу запустить любой скрипт/бота, хелп!

Tags: python, discord

Пытаюсь запустить данный скрипт для выдачи ролей:

```
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.utils import get
import discord

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='/')

@bot.command(pass_context=True)
@commands.has_role("123") # This must be exactly the name of the appropriate role
async def addrole(ctx):
    member = ctx.message.author
    role = get(member.server.roles, name="Test")
    await bot.add_roles(member, role)

    client = MyClient()
client.run('Тут стоит мой токен :) ')
```

Далее пишу в консоль python GGG.py
Выдаёт ошибку

```
 : Имя "python" не распознано как имя командлета, функции, файла сценария или выполняемой программы. Проверьте правильность написания имени, а также наличие и п
равильность пути, после чего повторите попытку.
строка:1 знак:1
+ python GGG.py
+ ~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (python:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

А до этого писало вообще вот это:

```
yntaxError: invalid syntax
>>> & C:/ProgramData/Anaconda3/python.exe c:/Users/lenovo/Desktop/python/GGG.py
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    & C:/ProgramData/Anaconda3/python.exe c:/Users/lenovo/Desktop/python/GGG.py
```

Теперь пишет

```
PS E:\Bots> & E:/Program_Files_x86/Python/python.exe e:/Bots/GGG.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "e:\Bots\GGG.py", line 1, in <module>
    from discord.ext import commands
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'discord'
```

Answer (score 0):

Вам стоит сначала импортировать модуль `discord`, только после этого из него импортировать функции.

Попробуйте изменить импорты вот так:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.utils import get
```

Comment: У него это написано.

Answer (score 0):

У меня была схожая проблема. Но на Ubuntu.
Нужно просто использовать при запуске команду не `python GGG.py` а команду `python3 GGG.py`